# Circular Permutation Problem with overlapping patterns

Tags: permutation-cycles

Intro:
We know that if there are two symbols, e.g. a and b, giving two spaces to place these two types of symbols at random, there will be $2^2 = 4$ distinct ways if the order matters: {aa, bb, ab, ba}. The minimum length of a circular arrangement that includes each of the four two-place patterns at least once is **abba** or **baab**.

I am stuck at the following question:
If we have n symbols, with m spaces, then there will be $n^m$ possible distinct ways to arrange these symbols. What is the minimum length of the circular arrangement that contains each of the $n^m$ patterns at least once?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence

Comment: Amazing! Thank you @JaapScherphuis ^_^